# Refused to execute script from

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am getting this error While accessing this URL via ajax with jasonp datatype.
Please help someone  to resolve this issue

Refused to execute script from `'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw4SWi16wWTR622NUVlsFacqrCWz7KB8DaZ…020319074134340642_1499172512130&name=dfgdg&comment=dfgdfg&_=1499172512131' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: use type "application/javascript".

Comment: Your link looks broken, and I don't want to have to click on a link to a script like that. Please provide more information,

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl <your link> 
> moved permanently to <new link>

$ curl <new link>
> moved permanently to:

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&amp;passive=1209600&amp;continue=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw4SWi16wWTR622NUVlsFacqrCWz7KB8DaZ/&amp;followup=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw4SWi16wWTR622NUVlsFacqrCWz7KB8DaZ/

$ curl -I <final link>

> ...
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> ...
```

So the script is delivered as html, you need to change that on the server.